# JavaScript: Status bar not displaying mouseover text with links IE9

Tags: javascript, xhtml, internet-explorer-9

When running the below code, it fails to display the text I wrote. Instead, it displays in the status bar the URI of the link. Why is this happening?

`<a href="link" onmouseover="self.status='your text';" onmouseout="self.status='';">link here</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.status` isn't a standard property. It has been eliminated for security reason. You can't do that on modern browsers (including IE9).

You'll have to find another solution, like for example making a small div at the bottom left corner :

```
<a href="link" 
onmouseover="document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='your text';"
onmouseout="document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='';">link here</a>
<div id=status style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0"></div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, this is perfect for what I wanted to know. Thanks for the code and demonstration.

Comment: the link demonstration does not work 404 not found please provide new one

Answer (score 1):

Being able to modify the status bar information is an excellent way to mislead users into thinking that a link will take them to Place They Want To Be instead of Place That Will Steal Their Password… so browsers don't let page authors mess with it any more.

> Internet Explorer 7 limits the ability of Web pages to use scripts to write information to the status bar. This ability is restricted by default for the Internet Zone, and is subject to user-configurable settings for Trusted and Restricted Sites Zones. This is part of the work to ensure that users are not misled by Web pages. Calls to window status will fail silently in cases where updates are not allowed.

— [Security and Compatibility in Windows Internet Explorer 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

HTML has a title attribute designed specifically to provide advisory information about an element. Use that to display status information.

```
<a href="link" title="your text">link here</a>
```

Comment: I had tried this and it does work but wanted to know a way around this. Thanks